# Troubles with root partition running full

Tags: linux, partitioning, disk-space, zypper

When I originally installed my opensuse-leap distro (42.1), I took the recommended size for the root partition, which was 40gb. At the meantime I upgraded to 42.2 (Plasma 5.8.6) and today, when  I was working on my machine, strange things happened: e.g. the hp-setup gui for my lan-printer froze, which wasn't killable by `kill -9`, etc..

So I rebooted my machine and suddenly the login gui didn't show up anymore, so in my desperation I switched to the virtual terminals via Strg+Alt+F1. There I noticed my `/` was 100% full via `df -h` after that was hinted by not being able to use my bash-history anymore (something like `cannot access ... anymore, no free space on device`). Then I tried to uninstall some "unnecessary" packages like digikam via zypper, which didn't run smoothly (was regularly saying: page fault ... no free space on device). This ended in `df -h` still saying 100% of `/` used, despite the disk usage was only `38Gb` vs. `40Gb` in total.

So, in the end, I deleted all files >1MB in /tmp (which is dangerous, I know) and typed `rpm --rebuilddb` and now I have 25% (i.e. 10Gb) of free space and can work on my system without any nerve-killing problems due to 100% disk-usage again.

So, my questions are:

- Is there any mechanism in zypper, that can warn me, when due to new installable packages, upgrades etc. the limit, say 99% `/` usage, is reached, so that I will not install the packages or clean up my root partition before?
- Is it better to use a cronjob, to regularly clean up some files of the e.g. `/tmp/` directory or `/var/` directory (or some other directory?), which haven't been accessed for a long time?
- Should I take a deeper look at my installed packages and selectively remove "unnecessary" packages?

Comment: 40GB seems quite a lot for just packages. For some damage assessment do `sudo du -hsc /boot /usr /var /tmp` to have an idea of where all that space went (include `/opt` in the scan if you have one) (13G total for me).

Comment: Ah, I found out what spammed my `/` partition. After I started the gui variant of /usr/bin/hp-setup the gui-window froze again and suddenly in my `/tmp`, a file: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11G Jul 17 16:19 /tmp/YaST2-04701-priClT/stdout` appeared which is `11gb` big!!! How is this possible, is this a major bug in the `hp-setup` binary?

Comment: I won't comment on HP. This said 30GB is still a bit much.

Comment: I must say, that I use btrfs as a fs for my root partition. I ran your suggested command on alll dirs except `/.snapshot`, which gave me a total of 17GB. This means, that I have ~13GB of snapshot content, which is obviously a bit much. As I`m no btrfs expert, I should figure out how to shrink that,